# Entity Framework Repository Not Working with Multi-Level .Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository

I'm working with a large project where someone else set up the Repository classes using Entity Framework. I realize some of the issue may be related to custom code, but could anyone help me determine where to look next?

I'm trying to write this query:

```
List<ProductItem> addedProductItems =
    repository.Query<ProductItem>()
        .Include(pi => pi.Product)
        .Include(pi => pi.ProductItemVendors.Select(v => v.ProductPricings))
        .Where(pi => !pi.IsDeleted && productIdSortOrder.Keys.Contains(pi.ProductId))
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(pi => productIdSortOrder[pi.ProductId])
        .ToList();
```

But the line with the second `.Include()` produces the following error. (The first `.Include()` works fine.):

> Error  5   The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity2' in the generic type or method 'VIP.Domain.Repository.IRepositoryObjectQuery.Include(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'Leo.Domain.ILeoDomainModelItem'.

This is how the interface that includes `Include()` is defined:

```
public interface IRepositoryObjectQuery<TEntity, TEntityMarker>
    : IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IListSource
    where TEntity : TEntityMarker
{
    IRepositoryObjectQuery<TEntity, TEntityMarker> Include<TEntity2>(IRepositoryPropertyChain<TEntity, TEntity2> propertyChain) where TEntity2 : TEntityMarker;
    IRepositoryObjectQuery<TEntity, TEntityMarker> Include<TEntity2>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity2>> propertyGetter) where TEntity2 : TEntityMarker;
    IRepositoryObjectQuery<TEntity, TEntityMarker> Include<TEntity2>(Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TEntity2>>> propertyGetter) where TEntity2 : TEntityMarker;
}
```

Could anyone see what might be the issue here?

Comment: How is the model defined? Particularly, how are ProductItem, ProductItemVendors and ProductPrincings defined and related?

Comment: What is a `ILeoDomainModelItem`?

Comment: @JotaBe: I figured that would be apparent. ProductPricing has a foreign key to ProductItemVendors, and ProductItemVendors has a foreign key to ProductItem.

Comment: @DavidG: It's really just a marker class to show something is an entity.

Comment: Please show the `ProductItem` class, esp. the code of `ProductItemVendors`. It doesn't seem to be a mapped property.

Comment: @GertArnold: These are entity classes. All other references to them, and the references between them, seem to work fine. The property in question appears as `public virtual ICollection<ProductItemVendor> ProductItemVendors { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the expression

```
pi => pi.ProductItemVendors.Select(v => v.ProductPricings)
```

is not an `ICollection<T>` and presumably not an `IRepositoryPropertyChain`, so the only overload in which it may be used is

```
IRepositoryObjectQuery<TEntity, TEntityMarker> Include<TEntity2>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity2>> propertyGetter) 
    where TEntity2 : TEntityMarker;
```

Due to the type constraint, `TEntity2` must be derived from/implement `TEntityMarker` (which is apparently `Leo.Domain.ILeoDomainModelItem`).  `IEnumerable<TypeOfProductPricings>` (the result of the include expression) does not implement that interface.